# C# Express: How to publish project for use with 3rd party installer (msi)?

Tags: c#, deployment, publish

I want to publish my c# project (c# 2008 express edition) and create an (msi) installer with Inno Setup Compiler. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set build mode to "Release" and then take everything inside the `\bin` directory and toss it into you MSI.

The VS Express editions do NOT include a built-in method for creating an MSI like the VS Pro/Ultimate do.

Comment: I can't find any way to set the build mode in VS Express edition. Are all those extra files needed in my Release folder? Like projectname.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache, projectname.Form1.resources, etc.

Comment: The only things you should need from the Bin folder are the DLLs and possibly the .configs.

Comment: If you want to build Release in VS Express, go to: "Tool -> Options". Make sure that "Show all settings" is checked, then go to: "Projects and Solutions -> General" Check the option "Show advanced build options".